# Add Stacked Bar Graph into Dashboard

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

I have code that creates a dashboard but when trying to add a stacked bar graph into the dashboard as the "G9" plot (all my other graphs that are either line or normal bar work fine), it produces the plot as a separate graph and not within the dashboard.

Any thoughts on how to get my desired graph anchored into the G9 slot of the dashboard?

https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html

```
plt.figure(figsize=(30,30))
grid= plt.GridSpec(18,2, wspace =0.1, hspace=1.0)
plt.suptitle('ED Dashboard ' + DateRange, fontsize=30)

g1 = plt.subplot(grid[0:2, 0:1])
g2 = plt.subplot(grid[0:2, 1:3])
...
g9 = plt.subplot(grid[14:18, 0:3])

g9=px.bar(ALL_BOARD, x="Date", y=["Acute_Count", "ICU_Count", "PSYCH_Count"], title="ED Total Boarders by Unit")
```

Comment: you are trying to mix oil and water... matplotlib and plotly are fully independent libraries so you can't add a plotly figure as a subplot to a matplotlib gridspec

Answer (score 0):

With help from this website, this code worked. Only issue now is that values are not showing on the y axis. https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/12-stacked-barplot-with-matplotlib

```
bars = np.add(ALL_BOARD["Acute_Count"], ALL_BOARD["ICU_Count"]).tolist()

g9.bar(ALL_BOARD['Day'], ALL_BOARD["Acute_Count"], label='Acute_Count',color=('blue'))
g9.bar(ALL_BOARD['Day'], ALL_BOARD["ICU_Count"],  bottom=ALL_BOARD["Acute_Count"],label='ICU_Count', color=('red'))
g9.bar(ALL_BOARD['Day'], ALL_BOARD["PSYCH_Count"], bottom=bars,label='PSYCH_Count', color=('black'))
loc = WeekdayLocator(byweekday=MO, interval=1)
g9.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
g9.set_ylabel('Boarding Counts')
g9.tick_params(labelrotation=22.5)
g9.set_title('ED Total Boarders by Unit')
g9.legend(["Acute_Count","ICU_Count","PSYCH_Count"],
         loc='upper left', frameon=False)
```